# Alternatives of OpenID/OAuth2.0 for first-party (main) application without redirect to login page?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-page-application, openid

1. I would like to know if there exists alternative for OpenID/Oauth2.0 for first-party apps like public SPA without redirecting user to OpenID login page?
   I know there exists password grant type, but it's deprecated as written in Oauth2.0 docs.
2. And if there is no alterative solution, is it good choice to implement only JWT issuer (auth) service without OpenID on my own? Will it be still secure? If yes, then which details should I take into consideration?

Comment: Have you found a satisfactory answer to this question? I'm curious whether OAuth 2.0 (first-party) is still a viable choice for trusted first-party mobile app clients or a first-party trusted single-page application (SPA), and whether there is a way to obtain a token directly via an HTTP request flow using user credentials obtained from the native mobile app's login screen

Answer (score 0):

If you have a first-party app, which only talks to your backend then it should be enough to use sessions. You don't need to implement OAuth and JWTs, and using sessions will solve some you some security issues with tokens (e.g. how to securely store them in the browser).

If you do decide to use access tokens I highly recommend implementing OAuth or OIDC, as this will mitigate some common security vulnerabilities.